# Sharepoint: Problem with search refinement when values contain spaces

Tags: sharepoint, search

I have a search people search page that makes use of `RefineSearchResults` where I can define which field I want the search refined by. This is setup and works to some extent, but I am experiencing problems whenever the column contains values with spaces in it.

Say I wanted to refine the search by `OfficeNumber` (from AD, not really a number) and I choose to refine the search by "Main" it works just fine, I only get people who have that OfficeNumber. However, if I try to refine the search by "Next door" I get no results and in the search box it shows: `officenumber:Next door`, which seems to indicate that it searches by `Next` instead of `Next door`, but I can't make any group markers such as " stick - it's gone when I hit enter.

Is there any way to fix this so that it can refine the search by values with spaces in them?

Comment: By group markers, do you mean single and double quotation marks?

Comment: Yes, I even tried triple double quotation marks """text""", but it all gets removed when it is submitted.